# Как ограничить значение переменной?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу реализовать в своей игре уровни предметов, но как сделать максимальный уровень? Например, что бы он был 30. Есть идея, при прокачке уровня если он будет равнятся 30, то просто пропадет кнопка, но как сделать это грамотно? Помню, как-то ограничивал значение поворота камеры, что бы нельзя было вертеть головой на 360 градусов вверх. Возможно, с помощью  функции Math.Lerp, но я не помню) Подскажите.

Comment: `Как ограничить значение переменной?` - `myVariable = Math.Min(30, myVariable);`

Comment: Но ведь это нужно будет вызывать постоянно при прокачке уровня. Можно вместо этого написать просто `if (myVariable > 30) myVariable = 30;`

Comment: Можно и так. Оформите ответом? :)

Comment: Мне нужно что бы переменная была "ограничена" постоянно, а не каждый вызов.

Comment: А если использовать не переменную, а своиство. А ограницение установоте в операторе set

Comment: Хм, а это идея. Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev будьте добры, оформите ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать не переменную, а свойство. А ограничение установить в операторе set

```
    private int _myVariable;

    public int myVariable
    {
        get { return _myVariable; }
        set
        {
            _myVariable = Math.Min(30,value);
        }
    }
```